# python service restart (when compiled to exe)

Tags: python, windows-services, restart

I have a service, as follows:

```
"""
The most basic (working) CherryPy 3.1 Windows service possible.
Requires Mark Hammond's pywin32 package.
"""

import cherrypy
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import sys
import __builtin__

__builtin__.theService = None

class HelloWorld:
    """ Sample request handler class. """

    def __init__(self):
        self.iVal = 0

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

        try:

            self.iVal += 1 

            if self.iVal == 5:
                sys.exit()
            return "Hello world! " + str(self.iVal) 

        except SystemExit:
            StopServiceError(__builtin__.theService)


class MyService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    """NT Service."""

    _svc_name_ = "CherryPyService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "CherryPy Service"
    _svc_description_ = "Some description for this service"

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        __builtin__.theService = self
        StartService()


    def SvcStop(self):
        StopService(__builtin__.theService)


def StartService():

    cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloWorld(), '/')

    cherrypy.config.update({
        'global':{
            'tools.log_tracebacks.on': True,
            'log.error_file': '\\Error_File.txt',
            'log.screen': True,
            'engine.autoreload.on': False,
            'engine.SIGHUP': None,
            'engine.SIGTERM': None
            }
        })

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()


def StopService(classObject):
    classObject.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    cherrypy.engine.exit()
    classObject.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)


def StopServiceError(classObject):
    classObject.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    cherrypy.engine.exit()
    classObject.ReportServiceStatus(serviceStatus=win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED, win32ExitCode=1, svcExitCode=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyService)
```

I want windows to restart the service when the sys.ext() cause the service to exit.  Does anyone know how to make it do this?

Comment: Try the answer to this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220382/how-can-a-windows-service-programmatically-restart-itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220382/how-can-a-windows-service-programmatically-restart-itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non programming-related option:

A windows service can be configured for recovery. Select the `recovery` tag of the `service properties` window. You can select to `Restart the Service` after the first, second or subsequent failures.

A simple idea - why don't you drop the `sys.exit()` call? This way the service just continues to run and you don't have to deal with restarting it. If you really need to know when `self.iVal` reaches `5`, you can report to the event logger (and perhaps reset the counter).

Comment: I've done this, but it still does not restart the service after a minute.

Comment: Look for clues in eventlog items under system / service control manager.

Comment: @gimel, this "non-programming option" **doesn't work**. Python services built with py2exe are not restarted after failure even when Windows is configured to do so in the way you suggest.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me when using and EXE compiled with pyinstaller.  `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGABRT)` did not work. `sys.exit(-1)` is still required if the program does not end with a non-zero code on it's own.

Comment: @rlat your comment is unclear. How exactly did you get this to work?

Comment: And are you using pyinstaller in one-file or one-folder mode?

Comment: @ModestLeech My answer is 6 year old so I don't work with this any more and have only a vague recollection of what the solution (or problem) was. What I think I was trying to say was "If the services doesn't exit with non-zero code, it will not be restarted" (because zero code mean success / planned termination).

Comment: @rlat thanks for the response. I got it working in the end

Answer (score 2):

I've had exactly the same issue: trying to make a Python-based service exit with an error code so that the services framework can restart it. I tried the approach with `ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, win32ExitCode=1, svcExitCode=1)` as well as `sys.exit(1)` but none of them prompted Windows to restart the service, despite the latter showing up as an error in the event log. I ended up not relying on the services framework and just doing this:

```
def SvcDoRun(self):
    restart_required = run_service() # will return True if the service needs
                                     # to be restarted
    if restart_required:
        subprocess.Popen('sleep 5 & sc start %s' % self._svc_name_, shell=True)
```

Comment: os.kill( os.getpid(), signal.SIGABRT)