# Programmatically restart a Java application that can be run as a windows service

Tags: java, windows, service, restart

I'm trying to get my Java application to be able to restart itself programmatically.

I already have a working solution for when it's executed as a standalone application - the application invokes java.exe with its own classpath, jvm parameters, class name, and command line arguments; and then it exits (see my [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886999/3199595)).

But this approach doesn't work cleanly when the application is run as a windows service - instead of a restarted service, I end up with a java.exe process executed by the SYSTEM account, and the state of the service is stopped (since it exited). So the application does restart, but is no longer a service.

I know that windows [restarts services that exit with a non-zero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220382/how-can-a-windows-service-programmatically-restart-itself) but **a)** I'm not sure that it always works (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764187/windows-services-recovery-not-restarting-service) question) **b)** I'm not sure how to identify the fact that the application is running as a windows service in the first place - `System.getProperty("user.name")` just seemed to return the hostname followed by a dollar sign ($) in my tests.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Configuration_file) package has a `<restartOnCrash>` parameter for services.