# can I set the restart/recovery properties for a windows service from code?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I am referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220382/how-can-a-windows-service-programmatically-restart-itself) answered question...

I see that one can manually configure a service to restart using Services control panel. Is there a way to set these values in code, either from the Service itself or, more likely, from the Service Installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS` option of the [ChangeServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681988.aspx)  function.

Comment: I was hoping there was a .net implementation, but this should do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did not specify it in my original question, but I am working in c#./net, and had some trouble getting the calls to win32 just right (I don't have a lot of experience in this area). In the end, I found a nice implementation/explanation, which helped me finally get it right.

Here's the link:

http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=277&artID=7660