# One windows service trying to start another: access denied

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am running a Windows service on my production server.  It is super-important that we have immediate recovery if the service crashes for any reason, so I wrote a monitor service whose sole purpose in life is to keep checking that the main service is up and running, and if it's not, to send out a distress signal.  It's also supposed to start up the service that's down... and that's the part that's not working:

```
public static void CheckService(string checkServiceName, string myServiceName, bool restartIfStopped = false)
{
    var ctl = ServiceController.GetServices()
         .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == checkServiceName);
    var error = "";
    if (ctl == null)
        error = "{0} is not installed!".Fmt(checkServiceName);
    else if (ctl.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        error = "{0} is in status {1}".Fmt(checkServiceName, ctl.Status);
        if (restartIfStopped)
            try
            {
                ctl.Start();
                // no error = success
                error += "\r\nService was automatically restarted.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // send to windows application log
                Log("Failed to restart service:\r\n"+ex, myServiceName, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            }
    }
    // other code here to send out email notifications
}
```

The problem is that when I try to restart the service with `ctl.Start()`, it exceptions out with the following error in the application log:

> Failed to restart service:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open MyService service on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Both services are set to run using "Network service".  I have granted full security permission to "Network Service" on both the executable folders.

What else could be causing this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can set up the service to restart automatically in case of failure?

Comment: @GabrielNegut you're right! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/220451/7850).  You want to put that as an answer, for credit?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I added it as an answer (with the link you provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the service to restart in case of failure (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220382/how-can-a-windows-service-programmatically-restart-itself/220451#220451)).

Comment: Thanks!  I've marked this as the correct answer, but if anyone subsequently comes up with a specific solution for the "access denied" problem, I'll give them credit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its an Administrative Permission.

I would try 2 things

1. Add Application Manifest to the solution, for more details refer : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/629067/How-to-add-a-manifest-file-in-my-project
2. Give Manual rights

Go to c://Program Files/ApplicationFolder/.exe Right click on .exe and go to Properties then go Compability Tab and check true to Run this Program as an administrator Level.

Comment: requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly how to do each of these steps?

Comment: Have added link for the 1st one and for 2nd steps already explained.

Comment: Hmmm... I think it's a bit heavy handed to make the services run with administrative rights.  There's got to be a more focused and accurate way to work around this.