The issue of a Windows service not restarting using C#,
I have a Windows service that is supposed to restart itself after a specified time using a method called ServiceRestartTimer. I'm installing this service on Windows Server 2019.
When the service reaches the Stop state, it seems to stop completely, and the rest of the code doesn't execute anymore.
Based on the logs I've added, I realized this is what's happening.
This is my code:
if (AppConfiguration.RestartTimeMin != 0)
{
    RestartTimeer.Elapsed += ServiceRestartTimer;
    RestartTimeer.Start();
}

In this section, which runs after the OnStart method, I call the ServiceRestartTimer method, which goes to the following method:
private void ServiceRestartTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan diff = now - LatestReadTime;

        Log.WriteToFile("Service Entered ServiceRestartTimer at: " + now.ToString());

        // Checking if the delay exceeds the allowed time
        if (diff.TotalSeconds > RestartTimeInSec)
        {
            Ping myPing = new Ping();

            // Executing Ping asynchronously
            myPing.PingCompleted += (pingSender, pingEventArgs) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    PingReply reply = pingEventArgs.Reply;

                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Log.WriteToFile("ReStart Service Is Called: " + " In Time : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                        try
                        {
                            // Using ServiceController to control the service
                            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService");

                            // Checking the service status before stopping
                            if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                            {
                                Log.WriteToFile($"Service MyService is currently running. Attempting to stop it.");
                                sc.Stop();
                                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)); // Wait for the service to stop
                                Log.WriteToFile($"Service MyService stopped successfully.");
                            }

                            // Restarting the service after stopping
                            sc.Start();
                            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)); // Wait for the service to start
                            Log.WriteToFile($"Service MyService started successfully.");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log.WriteToFile($"Error restarting service: {ex.Message}");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.WriteToFile("Ping failed. Service restart skipped.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.WriteToFile("Exception in PingCompleted handler: " + ex.Message);
                }
            };

            // Sending Ping asynchronously
            myPing.SendAsync(AppConfiguration.IP, 1000, null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WriteToFile("Exception in ServiceRestartTimer: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

This log:

Log.WriteToFile("ReStart Service Is Called: " + " In Time : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

is printed, and so is this log:

Log.WriteToFile($"Service MyService is currently running. Attempting to stop it.");

But when sc.Stop(); is executed, the next log:

Log.WriteToFile($"Service MyService stopped successfully.");

is not printed, and it seems like the service stops completely, and the rest of the code doesn't run anymore.
I expect that when this method is reached, it should correctly perform the service restart operation.
I have tested various implementations, but none of them worked.

When you say this runs "after" the OnStart method, do you mean it runs completely separately after OnStart is finished, or is it called within OnStart? That aside, calling Stop via the service controller is sending a stop signal to this process. It makes sense that it will terminate immediately rather than finish executing this method.

Have you considered using the the restart facilities of the Service Control Manager (aka, the SCM). You can configure a service for automatic restart in the Services applet or in your Service's installer. Once you call Stop on a service, it's gone - don't expect any of your code to run after that

Some options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220382/how-can-a-windows-service-programmatically-restart-itself
